# How can I launch a Python script from Spotlight on macOS?

Tags: mac, python

Say I have a hello.py file in /Users/jsmith. How can I easily run this script from Spotlight? Ideally, I'd like to save myself the trouble of opening a Terminal or Finder window to run it.

Do I have to place a #! /usr/bin/env python3 shebang line at the top? Does it have to be in a folder on the PATH environment variable? I need a way to quickly run a Python script with minimal fuss.

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877741/how-to-run-a-shell-script-using-spotlight) suggests, you can create a `.command` script that runs the Python script. For example, this should work:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python /Users/jsmith/hello.py
```

Then, to run it you can just search for its filename, select it, and hit enter.

*Remember that you'll have to make the `.command` file executable: `chmod a+x hello.command` (replace `hello.command` with the filename).*